# How to indicate authors' affiliation correctly in order?

Tags: titles, author-number

If I have three authors listed according to their contributions and one author listed in the middle has different affiliation than others. Hence the title should look roughly like this:
[image]

How can I do this? I am using IEEEtran class.

Here is the code I tried:

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Title of Paper}

% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Sk. Adnan Hassan\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Dipto Das\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Anindya Iqbal\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Amiangshu Bosu\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}, Rifat Shahriyar\IEEEauthorrefmark{5}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\
Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology\\
Bangladesh\\
Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}adnan20049@gmail.com,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}dipto.cse.buet@gmail.com,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}anindya@cse.buet.ac.bd,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{5}rifat@cse.buet.ac.bd},
}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Computer Science\\
Southern Illinois University\\
Carbondale, IL, USA\\
Email:\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}abosu@cs.siu.edu,
}

\maketitle

\input all.tex
\end{document}
```

I ran into error saying misplaced crcr.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hi @samcarter, I have added my code snippet to the question.

Comment: @CarLaTeX thank you. The guide was helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, thank you for having read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had unbalanced parenthesis:

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
    \title{Title of Paper}
    \author{%
        \IEEEauthorblockN{
            Sk. Adnan Hassan%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
            Dipto Das%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
            Anindya Iqbal%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{3},
            Amiangshu Bosu%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{4},
            Rifat Shahriyar%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{5}
        }
        \IEEEauthorblockA{
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}
            Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\
            Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology\\
            Bangladesh
            \\
            Email:%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}adnan20049@gmail.com,
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}dipto.cse.buet@gmail.com,
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}anindya@cse.buet.ac.bd,
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}rifat@cse.buet.ac.bd}

        \IEEEauthorblockA{%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}
            Department of Computer Science\\
            Southern Illinois University\\
            Carbondale, IL, USA\\
            Email:%
            \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}abosu@cs.siu.edu
        }
    }


    \maketitle

    All
    %\input all.tex

\end{document}
```

By formatting your code, it becomes easier to see it.

[image]